# display grand total sales in column

Tags: sql-server

how to display month sales grand total in column for this query

```
select CONCAT(month(date),'-',YEAR(DATE)) as month, branch ,sum(total) as total
from BRANCH_SALES
where  DATE  between '20220101' and '20220131' and branch = '701'
group by CONCAT(month(date),'-',YEAR(DATE)),
Branch
ORDER BY total
```

what I'm looking for

| month | branch | total | grand total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 701 | 2345 | 7845 |
| 01-2022 | 702 | 4000 | 7845 |
| 01-2022 | 703 | 1500 | 7845 |

Comment: Where does the value of `grand total` come from? The `SUM` of your values in the column` total` don't come close to 50,000.

Comment: the grand total  is the sum of branch monthly total ,there are other branches. edit the grand total

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Instead of `group by CONCAT(month(date),'-',YEAR(DATE)),` you can do `group by EOMONTH(date)` then you select `CONCAT(month(EOMONTH(date)),'-',YEAR(EOMONTH(DATE))) as month` or just `EOMONTH(date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a windowed `SUM`:

```sql
SUM(SUM(total)) OVER () AS GrandTotal
```

As the `OVER` clause doesn't have a `PARTITION BY` or `ORDER BY` clause, it'll give a `SUM` for the entire dataset.

Comment: As the total is already a sum, this will likely need to be `SUM(SUM(total)) OVER() AS GrandTotal`

Comment: Good point, @GarethD. I foolishly internally tested this on the OP's aggregate data, and thus didn't have aggregation in my query.